# Grails spring security fails to present the login page due to a redirect loop

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I have upgraded my current spring security plugins to

- spring-security-core-2.0-RC2
- spring-security-ui-1.0-RC1

**PROBLEM**

and I noticed that my login screen no longer shows up. In Chrome it says **This page has a redirect loop**

**STEPS TO RECREATE THE PROBLEM**

So I have tried to create a brand new application called Test to try to isolate the problem.

First, I installed the security and security-ui plugins by adding the following entries in the **BuildConfig.groovy**:

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"    
compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC1"
```

Second I ran the quick start command as follows:

```
grails s2-quickstart security Person Authority Requestmap
```

and it created 4 domain objects as follows under a package called security: Authority.groovy, Person.groovy, PersonAuthority.groovy and Requestmap.groovy

as well as added the following to my **Config.groovy**

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'security.Person'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'security.PersonAuthority'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'security.Authority'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'security.Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll']
]
```

Finally, I have run the app by doing a **grails run-app** command where I would expect the login page (**auth.gsp**) that now is no longer part of your code but of the plugin (by design) to be returned

```
C\myPathToGrails\.grails\2.2.2\projects\Test\plugins\spring-security-core-2.0-RC2\grails-app\views\login\auth.gsp
```

but instead I get a blank page stating that this page has a redirect loop.

I have also added the following staticRules, cleaning the app, and re-running it again to see if it would fix the problem but the redirect message still ocurred.

```
'/login/**':                      ['permitAll'],
'/login/auth/**':                 ['permitAll'],
'/login.gsp':                     ['permitAll']
```

Anybody has any idea of how to get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using **Requestmap** as security config type, your **controllerAnnotations.staticRules** does not have any effect.

You need configure rules in **RequestMap** table, and enable your login controller and public pages to anonymous can access without login like:

```
    new Requestmap(url: '/*', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save();
    new Requestmap(url: '/logout/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED,IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY').save();
    new Requestmap(url: '/login/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save()
    new Requestmap(url: '/index/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you made my day. These entries did not have to be there in the previous version.

Comment: I have similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726867/grails-2-4-spring-security-asset-pipeline. Please help

Comment: Where would I need to add these lines?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mr Ignacio Ocampo for your help.

These lines have to be added in bootstrap.groovy.

Thanks Alot.

```
class BootStrap {

    def springSecurityService
    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->

        println "In bootstrap Init"

        //Added so that these urls can be visible to everyone
        new Requestmap(url: '/*', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save();
        new Requestmap(url: '/logout/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED,IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY').save();
        new Requestmap(url: '/login/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save()
        new Requestmap(url: '/index/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save();


        println 'Bootstrap init done'


    }


    def destroy = {

    }
}
```