# how used Grails Spring Security Plugin (Requestmap)

Tags: grails-2.3

[Grails spring security fails to present the login page due to a redirect loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668999/grails-spring-security-fails-to-present-the-login-page-due-to-a-redirect-loop/25428120#25428120)

Where I must write this?

```
new Requestmap(url: '/*', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information obtained from [**Dynamic Request Maps**](http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/#dynamic-request-maps) section on Spring.io's blog post titled "Simplified Spring Security with Grails".

> To enable this mechanism, add the following to Config.groovy:
>
> ```
> import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType
> ...
> grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.Requestmap
> ```
>
> All you then have to do is create instances of the `Requestmap` domain
>   class, for example in `BootStrap.groovy`:
>
> ```
> new Requestmap(url: '/timeline', configAttribute: 'ROLE_USER').save()
> new Requestmap(url: '/person/*', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED').save()
> new Requestmap(url: '/post/followAjax', configAttribute: 'ROLE_USER').save()
> new Requestmap(url: '/post/addPostAjax', configAttribute: 'ROLE_USER,IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY').save()
> new Requestmap(url: '/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY').save()
> ```

Comment: Thanks :). Only in BootStrap?

Comment: No, but in whatever `.groovy` file that you need security routing in. `BootStrap.groovy` is just an example.