# Grails 2.4 spring security & Asset pipeline

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.4

This is what request map table contains:

```
'/', '/index', '/index.gsp', '/**/favicon.ico',
  '/assets/**', '/**/js/**', '/**/css/**', '/**/images/**',
  '/login', '/login.*', '/login/*',
  '/logout', '/logout.*', '/logout/*']
```

But no static resources are loaded in `login page`. every request to static resource redirects to `login/auth`.

Answer (score 0):

In my (Spring Security 2.0-RC4) application I have:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/'                 : ['permitAll'],
    '/searchable/**'    : ['permitAll'],
    '/index'            : ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp'        : ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**'        : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**'         : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**'        : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**'     : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico'   : ['permitAll']
]
```

and that is working without problems. Note that I use annotations.

It looks as if you use request mappings, and from the documentation I read that you probably create request mappings like this:

```
for (String url in [
  '/', '/index', '/index.gsp', '/**/favicon.ico',
  '/assets/**', '/**/js/**', '/**/css/**', '/**/images/**',
  '/login', '/login.*', '/login/*',
  '/logout', '/logout.*', '/logout/*']) {
       new Requestmap(url: url, configAttribute: 'permitAll').save()
   }
```

Perhaps you should consider to make a save(failOnError: true) to make sure, that you actually have data in your requestmap table.

Comment: All spring security configuration works well in 2.3 version. Now i have started a 2.4 project. The data is saving in database. I have tried to create a new sample application and there also the assets are not displayed by default after installation of spring security & asset pipe line plugin.

Comment: My application is running 2.4, but as I said, I'm using annotations. Have you tried to debug into spring security, perhaps it can give you a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you use request mappings. So have a look to
[Using Spring Security and Requestmap fails in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083494/using-spring-security-and-requestmap-fails-in-grails/29588932#29588932)

In addition to be sure your requestmap is ok you may flush your requestmap, e.g.:

```
new Requestmap(url: '/login/**', configAttribute: 'permitAll').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```