# Login page going to fav.ico in chrome

Tags: grails, spring-security

After successful login, control is going to fav.ico and showing blank page in Chrome browser.Some times it redirects to proper home page, some times it behaving wrongly.

Here is the version of Spring Security being used in my project.
Using Spring Security plugin :

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-SNAPSHOT"
runtime ":spring-security-core:2.0-SNAPSHOT"

'/js/**':           ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
'/css/**':          ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
'/images/**':       ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
'/login/**':        ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
'/logout/**':       ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
```

Related to the below solution,I am unable to find out where to make changes or not.
[Grails spring security fails to present the login page due to a redirect loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668999/grails-spring-security-fails-to-present-the-login-page-due-to-a-redirect-loop)

Answer (score 3):

You need a rule for fav.ico if none of the existing ones are a match, e.g.

```
'/**/fav.ico':  ['permitAll']
```

The problem is that when the browser requests the HTML, it asynchronously makes requests for the static resources as the page is parsed, and if you're not authenticated, Spring Security stores a `SavedRequest` with the most recent url so it can redirect back to that after logging in. But it will only store one, so the real url gets lost and replaced with a `SavedRequest` for the favicon request. As long as you have a rule that allows all CSS/JS/image/favicon requests, there will be only the initial `SavedRequest`.

Comment: I tried adding the changes you mentioned. But still its not solved.This soultion was alredy there in the link I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I probably found answer. Add '/favicon.ico=IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' in grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap of Config.groovy file, then clean and deploy the code. The issue of Favicon.ico will be solved.